# pytorch: how to identify ops that cannot be parallelized/bottlenecks in neural architecture

Tags: python, pytorch, parallel-processing, automatic-differentiation

I am trying.
Supposedly there are points in the network architecture that cannot be parallelized.
How do identify parts that cannot be parallelized in a given neural network architecture?
What factors other then the type of layers influence whether a model can be parallelized?

Context is trying to accelerate model training on GPU

Comment: What I recommend is to first detect your bottle neck. Another thing to try is to increase batch_size. You can  read this blog https://towardsdatascience.com/measuring-actual-gpu-usage-for-deep-learning-training-e2bf3654bcfd